# Get field from JsonPath in java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

How to get ***field*** from ***a:b:c:d:f:1.0*** property via JsonPath?

```
"a:b:c:d:f:1.0" : {
    "field" : "field"}
```

I tried with a:b:c:d:f:1.0.field but returns invalid path.

Comment: Show us the actual JSON and the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your syntax in the above. You have missed the `{` and `}` surrounding the object.

Colon `:` is used in JSON to sepate name value pairs and period `.` is also not allowed for names.

Assuming a JSON object as :

```
{
  "object" : {
    "field" : "field"}
}
```

You can get the value by expression `$.object`

When using JsonPath, you can get field via, `JsonPath.read([json_object], [expression])`

Comment: It's surround with { }. Maybe the problem is because property "a:b:c:d:f:1.0" has dot inside and because that returns invalid path

Comment: yes colon and period are not valid for name. It actually doesn't return an invalid path, it should be throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I got the field using the following code

`$.['a:b:c:d:f:1.0'].field`